# Populate HTML table with AJAX data in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I have the following AJAX script running in my Django template:

```
function create_table() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/data/",
        success: function(data){
            console.log('button clicked')
            console.log(data)
            //$('#table').html('<div class="test">' + data['Name'] +'</div>');
            //$('#table').load('table_to_load.html');

        },
        error: function(error_data){
            console.log("errorrr")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })
}
document.getElementById("create_table").onclick = function() {
    create_table();
    return false;
}
```

The purpose of this script is to create a HTML table upon button click populated by dictionary data fetched by the AJAX call.

The AJAX call collects the data correctly, however, I don't know how to go about inserting the table.

Should I write the table HTML in pure Javascript/jQuery inside the AJAX call? Or maybe load a pre-prepared HTML (how do I reference its directory inside the call?)?

My preferred method though would be to write the template for the table in Django's template tag language and somehow reference in it the data fetched by AJAX. Something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>dictionary key</th>
      <th>dictionary value</th>
    </tr>
 {% for key, value in dictionary.items %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ key }}</td>
       <td>
            <a href="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</a>
       </td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

But I am not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either way, but you seem like you are trying to do in in 1/2 of both ways.

You can use ajax to make a call and get back some json data, and then use that json object to build the html string and use jquery to insert that html at the correct point in your page - nothing wrong with that way imo, though I personally am not a fan of hand stitching together html statements (mostly because for complicated pages it gets hard to design them and debug them this way, but for small pieces its OK).

An alternative is to have jquery call django view (via a url you have defined), and have that django view make the database call and use a template that is already in your project as a html doc, and then render that template and data just like you would any other django page. That view would return an httpresponse containing html, and then jquery would just insert that html into the page as before.